# JDBC Postgres Failover with quorum based synchronous replication

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

Let's say I am using [quorum based synchronous replication](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/New_in_postgres_10#Quorum_Commit_for_Synchronous_Replication) with 2 node names in either `ANY` or `FIRST` in `synchronous_standby_names` of 3 node cluster.

I am trying to read from slave as discussed in [postgres jdbc doc](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html).

```
jdbc:postgresql://node1,node2,node3/accounting?targetServerType=preferSlave&loadBalanceHosts=true
```

Can someone let me know

1. How does a slave is selected? Is a slave randomly selected or a slave is preferred which has zero lag or the minimum lag?
2. Is there any setting in jdbc url which will only select the slave with zero replication and if no such slave exists then read will be sent to master ?

Version

- Postgres - 10.4
- Postgres JDBC Driver - 42.2.2

Comment: Have you considered reading the documentation (see https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html#connection-parameters at the end), and if you did, exactly what is still unclear?

Comment: Yes and my above two questions are still not clear.

Comment: I would think your first one is answered by _"read pool balances connections between slaves nodes"_, and given there is no property related to your second question, it should be clear that there is no such option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been answered in postgres mailing list in [this](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/BY2PR0701MB2056E88E2846EFE91865D913A5720%40BY2PR0701MB2056.namprd07.prod.outlook.com) thread.

> No I guess there is no such option. Maybe you raise a PR if you can :)
>
> what you can do at infra level is put your databases behind a Load
>   balancer (like haproxy or nginx) and have a health check based on lag
>   etc and only then Route the connections to that standby node else take
>   it off the load balancer.
>
> Regards, Vijay
>
> ---
>
> From: Debraj Manna  Sent: Sunday, June 17, 2018
>   2:42:46 PM To: Vijaykumar Jain Cc: pgsql-admin Subject: Re: [External]
>   JDBC Postgres Failover with quorum based synchronous replication
>
> Yes Vijaykumar you are right it is just a random shuffle while picking
>   a slave.
>
> https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/f78a639d1ed3c64e80e1fa107691b4af5945cb84/pgjdbc/src/main/java/org/postgresql/hostchooser/MultiHostChooser.java#L51
>
> Is there a way I can specify in the connection parameters to pick a
>   slave with zero lag else fall back to master?
>
> On Sun, Jun 17, 2018 at 2:11 PM, Vijaykumar Jain
>   > wrote:
>   I guess the distinction between master and secondary logic can be
>   looked up here(isMaster)
>   https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/f78a639d1ed3c64e80e1fa107691b4af5945cb84/pgjdbc/src/main/java/org/postgresql/core/v3/ConnectionFactoryImpl.java
>   and from within slaves iirc we did check the code and it is random
>   shuffle and does not support any custom logic to pick any slaves. I
>   might be wrong but I do remember looking it up in the source :)
>
> Regards, Vijay
>
> ---
>
> From: Debraj Manna >
>   Sent: Sunday, June 17, 2018 11:31:32 AM To: pgsql-admin Subject:
>   [External] JDBC Postgres Failover with quorum based synchronous
>   replication
>
> Hi
>
> Let's say I am using quorum based synchronous
>   replicationhttps://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/New_in_postgres_10#Quorum_Commit_for_Synchronous_Replication
>   either ANY or FIRST in synchronous_standby_names
>
> I am trying to read from slave as discussed
>   herehttps://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html.
>
> jdbc:postgresql://node1,node2,node3/accounting?targetServerType=preferSlave&loadBalanceHosts=true
>
> Can someone let me know
>
> 1. How does a slave is selected? Is a slave randomly selected or a slave is preferred which has zero lag or the minimum lag?
> 2. Is there any setting in jdbc url which will only select the slave with zero replication and if no such slave exists then read will
>      be sent to master ?

Answer (score 0):

The below is valid as of 2018-07-12 (pgjdbc 42.2.3)

`pgjdbc` connects to one server only, so it "selects a host to connect to" just once (when the connection is established).
It will reconnect only in case network connection fails and/or if connection pool issues `close()` (e.g. if connection fails to validate at some point).

That is if "lag" of a secondary server changes over time, then the connection might point to "stale" host even though it was "the best" at the time the connection was created.

In case you really need "best lag" kind of logic, then you should probably have several datasources at the application level (each one pointing to just one host), then get both connections, check the lag and use the appropriate connection for your business operation.
Of course you might want to cache the lag of a datasource to avoid requesting it multiple times per second.

Implementing "best slave" at `org.postgresql.Driver` level would likely be non-trivial (current logic just assumes single connection points to a single server, metadata gets cached, etc).

One might implement `DataSource` that provides "connections with best lag" out of underlying datasources, however it has never been requested/implemented.